# Why are my Rails helpers not working with shopify_app gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, shopify, shopify-app

I upgraded the `shopify_app` gem in my Shopify application from 7.x to 8.x and rails helpers stopped working properly.

What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inheriting from `ShopifyApp::AuthenticatedController` in the controller hierarchy used to work.

As of `shopify_app` gem version 8 the Rails helpers seem to break, at least in some cases.

Instead of inheriting from the `ShopifyApp::AuthenticatedController` (which remains in the gem for backwards-compatibility) you can `include` the `ShopifyApp::Authenticated` concern. This should make the helpers work again. From the [example app](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app/tree/master/example/app/controllers):

```
class AuthenticatedController < ApplicationController
  include ShopifyApp::Authenticated
end
```

More info in the [gem documentation](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app#authenticated).

If that does not work or isn't an option for you, [this medium post](https://medium.com/@darkrubyist/how-to-expose-ruby-on-rails-applications-helpers-to-shopify-app-gem-5edffcf3487d) has another approach for including helpers.

Comment: But my app misbehaves and request to authenticate after I added it. I am using api_version 2019-10